# ClassyEnum..In Place Editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, enums, best-in-place

I have a Problem Model:

```
class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
  classy_enum_attr :state, default: ->(enum) { enum.min }
end
```

An Enum Class

```
class State < ClassyEnum::Base
  def description
    fail 'Unimplemented'
  end
end

class State::Open < State
  def description
    'We are working, or will soon be working on this problem'
  end
end

class State::CustomerUpdate < State
  def description
    'We are waiting information from you'
  end
end
```

end

I want to be able to do inline editing of state and have the best_in_place gem.

show.html.erb looks like:

```
<%= best_in_place @problem, :state, type: :select, place_holder: @problem.state.to_s.humanize, :collection => State.select_options%>
```

My question is that the drop down list looks like:

```
open
customer_update
```

but I want it to display as:

```
Open
Customer Update
```

`State.select_options` returns

```
[["Open", "open"], ["Customer Update", "customer_update"]]
```

How do I display the first part of each enum not the second?

Thank you

Comment: Found the answer...best_in_place reverses the format to usual rails practice so did:   ***<%= best_in_place @problem, :state, type: :select,  :collection => State.select_options.map { |s| [ s[1], s[0] ]}**